# Sencha -> delta-updates, android-app not updating

Tags: android, cordova, extjs

Every time I update my android-app (Cordova with project-files embedded), the app is allways showing the old version (first version) of my app. If I go to android-settings -> apps, and clear the app-data, the app is showing the latest version of my app. But I can't ask all the users to do that every time there is an update.

Answer (score 0):

My only way for correct this has been built a script removing the local store every launch.

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
    //localStorage.clear();
    //DELETE APP.js of cache for reload
    Object.keys(localStorage)
          .forEach(function(key){
               //alert(key);
               var n = key.indexOf("app.js");
               var n2 = key.indexOf("pepe.css");
               if ((n>-1)||(n2>-1)) { 
                   localStorage.removeItem(key);
               }
           });
</script>
```